# assigning a $_GET variable to a JS variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, get

```
www.mywebsite.com/?foo=bar
```

How can I get the value of foo into a Javascript variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't even need PHP for that. Basically, you can parse `window.location.href` to get the value of a GET URL parameter into a JavaScript variable.

There is plenty of code online, you can use for example [this](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html):

```
function getUrlParameter( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

To get the value of `foo`, just call `getUrlParameter("foo")` in your JavaScript code.

Comment: `gup`? really? Come on. Descriptive function names!

Comment: Changed, although the code is taken from the link, so the name wasn't mine :)

Answer (score 1):

You can parse the `window.location.search` string for query variables.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location

For example

```
var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
var pairs = query.split('&');
var _get = {};
for (var i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
    var pair = pairs[i].split('=');
    _get[pair[0]] = pair[1];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some googling and here is a link for you http://www.zrinity.com/developers/code_samples/code.cfm/CodeID/59/JavaScript/Get_Query_String_variables_in_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
 function getUrlVars()
{
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
    hash = hashes[i].split('=');
    vars.push(hash[0]);
    vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
```

**EDIT**

The above will parse the URL and give you the parameters as an associative array. You can also try

```
function getURLVars(name) {
return decodeURI(
    (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
 );
}
```

In this if you want the value of `foo`, call this with `getUrlVars('foo')`